# Overlay image zoom out and move

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video with an image overlay. The picture is set nearly full screen for the first 10 seconds, and aftwerwards I need to zoom out the image to a smaller size and place it in the bottom left corner for the rest of the video.

At the moment I split the input image and overlay it twict to the video, without transitions, one for the "big" picture and one for the "small" picture and it works fine.
What I would like to make is a "zoom out and moove" effect to make it smoother from the big central picture to the small one.

This is my current complex filter:

```
-i "video.mp4" 
-i "img.jpg" 
-filter_complex "[1:v]split=2[img10][img20];[img10]scale=1469:856[img11];[img20]scale=293:171[img21];[0:v][img11]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2:enable='between(t,0,10)',fade=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1[vid];[vid][img21]overlay=10:(main_h-overlay_h-40):enable='gte(t,10)'" 
-crf 18 -c:a copy "out.mp4"
```

How can I make it as a single image overlay with zoom out + move effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ffmpeg version 4.3 or newer, you can animate the scale parameter. And then animate the overlay parameter.

```
ffmpeg
-i "video.mp4" 
-loop 1 -i "img.jpg" 
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w='if(between(t,10,14),1469-(1469-293)*(t-10)/4,if(lt(t,10),1469,293))':h='if(between(t,10,14),856-(856-171)*(t-10)/4,if(lt(t,10),856,171))':eval=frame[img];[0:v][img]overlay=x='if(between(t,10,14),(W-w)/2-((W-w)/2-10)*(t-10)/4,if(lt(t,10),(W-w)/2,10))':y='if(between(t,10,14),(H-h)/2-((H-h)/2-(H-h-40))*(t-10)/4,if(lt(t,10),(H-h)/2,H-h-40))':shortest=1" 
-crf 18 -c:a copy "out.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this but it goes out of the screen without resizind during the animation, any idea why? Looks like the overlay works, but the scale is not getting applied

Comment: Corrected exprs.

Comment: Now the overlay works like charm with the transition, but the image is not scaled and keeps the original size. I'm using ffmpeg version 2021-03-03-git-4dc039b4c7-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev ; dunno if  i'm missing something